How to adjust notification banner persistence/duration on macOS Sequoia
I'd like for the notifications on macOS Sequoia to stay onscreen for longer before they disappear. By the time I glance up at one, it is sliding off the screen.
Internet searches reveal (OLD) posts about using terminal to adjust bannerTime, but that appears to have no effect, even when assigning a very large value.
Anyone know how to do this on macOS Sequoia?
